# Need help to change working ffmpeg command to overlay instead of concatenate two audio files at specific position

Tags: ffmpeg

By asking another question here, I got working code

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=end=10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[begin];[0:a]atrim=start=10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[end];[begin][1:a][end]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" output
```

The code inserts second.mp3 into the input.mp3 at 10 seconds.

But now I need to overlay second.mp3 into the input.mp3 starting at 10seconds.
In other words I need playing input.mp3 and after 10 seconds I need start playing second.mp3 simultaneously.

The code I have been given keeps the params of input.mp3 and changes everything about second.mp3 to match input.mp3.

Could you help me altering the command I have to do the overlay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=10000|10000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix" output`

The adelay delays the 2nd audio start by 10 seconds. The amix mixes the two audios together.

Comment: An explanation what's changed and why would be helpful here for understanding the intent.  Thanks.

Comment: The command you gave worked perfectly, I just added after amix "=duration:first"..
I know that is completely another question... but how can I loop what you did?
Like input.mp3 plays all along, and in few random positions second.mp3 starts playing? With random delay.. lets say between 10 000 and 15 000..